# Why this URL Error in Codeigniter/Ajax?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, url, jquery

I am building an App in Codeigniter framework.. I have an Ajax function in the view file which calls to Controller(Me) function(getUser).. But i have to change the URL parameter in Ajax function if i change the way of triggering that function.
Code as follows

Method 1

```
$('#project').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "me/getUser"  // Controller name is added before func name
        }).done(function( html ) {
            $(".dashboard-project").html(html);
        });
    });
```

Method 2

```
$('#project').click(function(){
    ajaxfunc123();
   });

 ajaxfunc123(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getUser"    // Direct function called
      }).done(function( html ) {
           $(".dashboard-project").html(html);
      });
 }
```

Both the above method works..But i am troubled by why the change in URL is required if both function are on same page ?
can somebody plz explain me the reason or is it that i am doing it wrong way ?

Comment: direct function call is not allowed unless you use routing in Codeigniter

Comment: but the method 2 works in my code and that surprises me..and i havent used routing for calling this method

Answer (score 0):

did you use `index.php` or you removed that?

then you should try :

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('me/getUser'); ?>"
```

and

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('getUser'); ?>"
```

also do not forget about `data:{}` and `dataType:""` in your ajax calls